# How to get multiple count in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in my database in which I have two columns:

1. Username (`nvarchar(max)`)
2. Rating (`int`)

Now the user can enter a maximum number 5 in rating and minimum 1 now I have to query that how many times users save 1, how many times 2, how many times 3, how many times 4 and how many times 5

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Rating, COUNT(column_name)
FROM   TABLE
GROUP BY
       Rating
```